# Removing group of rows with sequence in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, window-functions

I'm trying to remove some rows from my data.frame. These unique rows are located in every 3rd group of my data.frame. 
here is the example `df`

```
set.seed(1)

AC <- rep(rep(c(78,110),each=1),times=18)
state <- rep(rep(c("Group 1","Group 2"),3),each=12)
V <- rep(seq(100,400,100),times=9)
R = sort(replicate(9, sample(5000:6000,4)))
df <- data.frame(AC,V,R,state)
```

> head(df)

```
   AC   V    R   state
1  78 100 5001 Group 1
2 110 200 5054 Group 1
3  78 300 5064 Group 1
4 110 400 5069 Group 1
5  78 100 5117 Group 1
6 110 200 5123 Group 1
```

They are sequenced by change in the `V` column. `V` column changes in every 100:400 sequence. So there are `3` groups in every `state` rows changes. 
I want to remove this `3rd` group in every group.
It might be also useful to add `No` column to remove this `3rd` column I think. for the example that I provide here is already `group_by` so only thing I need is add new `No` column and remove 3rd, 6th, 9nth.... of the groups of a data.frame.

I want to this process inside of a `dplyr` chain. Since I process my real data inside of `dplyr` chain. But I welcome any other function to do this.

the output which I look for

```
   No  AC   V    R   state
    1  78 100 5001 Group 1
    1 110 200 5008 Group 1
    1  78 300 5022 Group 1
    1 110 400 5055 Group 1
    2  78 100 5133 Group 1
    2 110 200 5163 Group 1
    2  78 300 5187 Group 1
    2 110 400 5189 Group 1
    4  78 100 5459 Group 2
    4 110 200 5467 Group 2
    4  78 300 5471 Group 2
    4 110 400 5501 Group 2
    5  78 100 5515 Group 2
    5 110 200 5531 Group 2
    5  78 300 5540 Group 2
    5 110 400 5553 Group 2
    7  78 100 5686 Group 1
    7 110 200 5717 Group 1
    7  78 300 5726 Group 1
    7 110 400 5755 Group 1
   ***********************
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide more data? Seeing your data and the expected outcome, I'd like to see more data.

Comment: My `head(df)` does not match yours after `set.seed(1)` so I'm having trouble matching up your reproducible example with your output.

Comment: Also, it looks like there are **9** values per unique (state, V), not 3?

Comment: @jazzurro I revised the expected output part.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I dont know thy you cannot reproduce. The important columns is `V` column change actually. So no need to worry about other cols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hard to understand your question, as when I copy your reproducible example my dataframe doesn't equal yours. But as I understand it, you simply want to number every set of 4 rows (according to `V`) and drop every third one.

In that case, try:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(No = cumsum(df$V == 100)) %>%
  subset(No %% 3 != 0)
```

The second row uses `df$V == 100` to mean "start of a new block of Vs" in order to assign the number.

In repsonse to your comment on the Q, I have not used the `state` column here (as in your reproducible example, every (state, V) has **9** rows not **3** as stated in the question...)

Note this assumes `df` is already ordered like in your question above (the Vs are in (100,200,300,400) repeating order, and the states alternate every 12 rows)